# type of Idris chop

Tags: types, functional-programming, idris, dependent-type

I'm trying to write a `chop` function in Idris. The Haskell equivlant would look like:

```
chop :: Int -> [t] -> [[t]]
chop n [] = []
chop n v = take n v : chop n (drop n v)
```

my initial attempt in Idris looks like:

```
chop : (n : Nat) -> Vect (k * n) a -> Vect k (Vect n a)
chop n Nil = Nil
chop n v = (take n v) :: (chop n (drop n v))
```

type checking error:

```
Type mismatch between
               Vect 0 a (Type of [])
       and
               Vect (mult k n) a (Expected type)

       Specifically:
               Type mismatch between
                       0
               and
                       mult k n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`k` can still be set as an argument, i.e. `chop {k=3} Z []` would result in `[[], [], []] : Vect 3 (Vect Z a)`. Your implementation would return `chop n Nil = []`, so Idris' type system correctly complains. :-)

You need to consider `k`:

```
chop : (n : Nat) -> Vect (k * n) a -> Vect k (Vect n a)
chop {k} n v = ?hole
```

If you want the actual implementation, here is a spoiler:

> It is quite similar to yours. Because `mult` recurses on the first argument (`k` in this case), `chop`'s recursion should also follow `k`:
>     `chop {k = Z} n v = []`
>     `chop {k = (S k)} n v = take n v :: chop n (drop n v)`

Another approach is to specify how many blocks you want instead of how big each block is.

```
chop' : (k : Nat) -> Vect (k * n) a -> Vect k (Vect n a)
chop' Z v = []
chop' {n} (S k) v = take n v :: chop k (drop n v)
```

`n` needs to be in scope to call `take` and `drop`.

Comment: I understand `chop {k = Z} n v = []`, but `chop {k = (S k)} n v = take n v :: chop n (drop n v)` less so could you possibly elaborate

Comment: Can you specify what is hard to understand? How to get from `chop {k = S k} … = ?hole` to the implementation?

Comment: Isn't there only one valid value of `k` for `n > 0`? is there anyway to rewrite chop so k doesn't have to be specified

Comment: Once you have a case where `k` is defined (`k = Z`) you should define it in the other cases, too. Otherwise Idris may or may not know that `k != Z` on other cases. Also, because `k` is the argument to recurse on (as `Vect k …` is the result), you need to split on it. You could drop `n` with another function like `chop' : (k : Nat) -> Vect (k * n) a -> Vect k (Vect n a)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what `chop'` would look like